# Hide Object Properties with Python

Tags: python, properties

I have been trying to make an Addon that uses Object Properties and have come up with the following code.

```
import bpy
bpy.types.Object.save_name2 = bpy.props.StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'}, name='Save Name')

first_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
first_object.save_name2 = "Bob"
```

I want to hide the property from Blender's ui so people can't change the values, however, the options=hidden does not seem to work.

[image]

Does anyone know how to hide the property? I have been looking around from awhile but i can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a property group class where you can store all your properties.

```
import bpy

class MaterialSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_int = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
    my_string = bpy.props.StringProperty()

bpy.utils.register_class(MaterialSettings)
```

Assigning these values to the Object like this:

```
bpy.types.Object.my_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MaterialSettings)
```

Note:
you can choose a custom name instead of 'my_settings'

And the name after the 'type=' is the classname of your property group .

You can access these properties like this: `object.my_settings.my_float = 3.0
object.my_settings.my_string = "Foo"`

This way, only the propertyclass will be visible in the properties tab and is only editable via script!

Comment: I think i understand. Would it be possible to get some example code for storing a property group on an object? I can't seem to figure out what (material.my_settings) is because it is not the name of the class or exists in it. Sorry for my lack of understanding as i am still trying to learn python.

Comment: Yes sure, let me update my post!

Comment: Man, you are awesome! It makes it read-only and combines all the properties in one property. Thanks for helping.