# Blender Dev. Custom properties set hide or non editable

Tags: python, drivers, properties, development

I was wondering if is a way to hide or set as non editable a custom property.

In Phyton i can use:

```
object[ label_property ] = value_property
```

I need to said... this is not for addon, maybe for a basic script or for set drivers.
I missing how to set properties of something? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This answer might have what you need, but it's not as simple: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58968/hide-object-properties-with-python

Comment: @ArmoredWolf  I search a little more... and see the link than you provided. If I don't miss anything, you response is the correct. Thanks man.